# WCf duplex communication with Jquery

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service and I need to setup the service to broadcast notifications to all the connected clients. However the call to WCF is made from jquery. So I need a method to be able to call back the jquery methods from WCF for broadcast. So basically I need a way to be able to call the jquery methods from WCF.

Please let me know if its possible and also any sample to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling WCF directly from JQuery for your scenario is not a good solution.

You cannot use WCF duplex outside intranet environments because of issues such as firewalls.

You have browser clients and you need to broadcast. Try using any implementations of xmpp such as [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Implementing SignalR from scratch is much easier than maintaining your current WCF code in this scenario.